# How does jacoco-report-aggregation generate the current project coverage report in gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

My project is divided into multiple modules according to functions.

```
- rain
  - rain-common
  - rain-service
  - rain-application
```

rain-application Depends on rain-common and rain-service, is a spring-boot project, which is packaged into Fat Jar using bootJar.

I configured `jacoco-report-aggregation` according to the gradle tutorial [Aggregating code coverage with JaCoCo](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_jvm_multi_project_with_code_coverage_distribution.html), but only the coverage of rain-common and rain-service is reported, the coverage of rain-application was not reported.

- rain-application/build.gradle

```js
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'jacoco-report-aggregation'

dependencies {
    implementation project(':rain-service')
    implementation project(':rain-common')
    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-spring:2.4-M1-groovy-4.0'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
testCodeCoverageReport{
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        html.enabled true
    }
}
check.dependsOn testCodeCoverageReport
test {
    ignoreFailures = true
    finalizedBy testCodeCoverageReport // report is always generated after tests run
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```

If I use the jacoco plugin, only rain-application's coverage is reported.

How to make jacoco-report-aggregation also report the coverage of the current module rain-application?

(Not every module runs a single test separately. My test code is all in the rain-application, which requires Servlet-Context)

Or for this kind of multi-module project to be packaged into Fat Jar, how should I configure gradle to get a global coverage report. Are there any best practices you can recommend?

Thanks!!!